# I am not able to install GCC in my Ubuntu(18.04)...I already tried the command - sudo apt install gcc

Tags: downloads, gcc

This is showing after typing the command to install GCC:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you enabled "Universe" repository in software-manager ?

Comment: @SorenA isn't `gcc` in the `main` repo?

Comment: I am not able to understand what you are saying...

Comment: @steeldriver, hmm, I just did a search that referred (some) gcc back to Universe, but now that you ask, I am not that sure.

Comment: So then..can you help me to install gcc?

Comment: @SorenA you can check with `apt policy gcc`

Comment: Did you install full Ubuntu or some other flavor like Lubuntu (because gcc is part of the normal installation)?  Did you run sudo apt-get update to update the package lists befoe trying to install anything else?

Answer (score 4):

As some comments have already pointed out, gcc is part of the main ubuntu repository. So technically, there should be a package `gcc`. You can search for all the packages that are available by running the command

```
apt-cache search gcc
```

This will show *all* packages that have gcc in their name (and that will likely be very many). You can narrow down the search to packages that start with gcc and then have a space (in other words, the package that really is called gcc),

```
apt-cache search gcc | grep "^gcc[[:space:]]"
```

If the former command found packages such as `gcc-8` or similar, but the latter command didn't show anything, then it is likely that your package management doesn't know about gcc. Some comments have also suggested to update the package database by running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This is generally a good idea before you install packages, because the installation will attempt to download whatever you try to install and that download may fail if (for example) the location of the package has changed. The command `apt-get update` makes sure everything is in the right place so that things can be found when you want to install them.

If after updating your package database (by `apt-get update`), you still don't find a package called `gcc`, but you do find one with a specific version number, the simplest way to get you a working gcc on your computer is probably to settle for a specific version, such as for example by running

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-7
```

You may have seen that some comments have pointed out that gcc would normally be part of an ubuntu installation. So the errors you are reporting might point at some more intricate problem with they way your package database is configured. If you are on a freshly installed ubuntu system, the simplest way to fix this is to simply re-install your system while you have a solid internet connection. If you are not on a freshly installed ubuntu system, things can be a bit more involved, but they are quite well documented if you search for ways to fix your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

Comment: Thank you very much..your suggestions helped me to install gcc..